# Counting visible rows within knockout foreach

Tags: knockout.js

I want to display a count on each row I'm showing. The rows come from an observable array of which only certain elements will be shown. This disqualifies the usual solution of using $index for this.

Markup:

```
<!-- ko foreach: { data: enterprise().Sessions, as: 'Session' } -->
<div data-bind="if: $root.isSessionVisible(Session)">

<b>
    <span data-bind="text: $index() + 1"></span>
</b>
```

What should I put instead of "$index() + 1" to display the actual count of displayed rows?

Thanks!

Comment: why not use [purely css counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Counters) for this, it will be faster and more maintanable. Just add a class for the visible elements so the counters apply only to them

Comment: Thanks Nikos, didn't know about the css counters. That worked perfectly! Just enter this as the answer and put some css sample code and I'll gladly give you the points.

Comment: You could also use a ko.computed to do the filtering and remove the if-logic from your HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done with knockoutjs methods, but i think it would be faster and more maintainable if done with [pure css counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Counters)

Example (html+css only shown):

**css**

```
body {
  counter-reset: session-active 1;
}
span.session.active::before {
  display: inline-block;  
  counter-increment: session-active; /* Increment the session counter*/
  content: "Session" counter(session-active) ": "; /* Display the counter */
}
```

**html** (per session item)

```
<b><span class="section active"></span></b>
```